# How do I make a call using Twillo on my Korea number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

If the sender is a US phone number, and the recipient is a Korean phone number, the code to transmit the characters succeeded with the code below.

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = "~~~"
auth_token = "~~~"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.messages.create(
    to="+821012341234",# korea phone number : 010-1234-1234
    from_="+18442414836", # United States phone number :(844) 241-4836
    body="    this is message text contents    "
)
```

However, the same error occurs when a caller dials a U.S. telephone number and a recipient dials a Korean telephone number.

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = "~~~"
auth_token = "~~~"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
    to="+821012341234",# korea phone number : 010-1234-1234
    from_="+18442414836", # United States phone number :(844) 241-4836
    url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
)

print(call.sid)
```

`twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 400 error: Unable to create record: Account not authorized to call +821012341234. Perhaps you need to enable some international permissions: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international`

How can I make a call to a Korean phone number?

I am wondering if it is free version, and the sending test to the Korean phone number is restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like your account is not currently allowed to make phone calls to Korea. However, you can fix this by going to the [geographic permissions for voice calls in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/geo-permissions/low-risk) and checking the right countries that you want to be able to call. That link, just to confirm, is https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/geo-permissions/low-risk